# How to create disposable AWS S3 client in Spring app?

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3

We have the Spring Boot 2 app, and there is such a task - we have previously persisted AWS S3 connection details (bucket, path, access, secret), and we need to create AWS S3 client on-the-flight, just to test connection with the given details.

I suppose that bean of `@Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)` is needed, but how to set these connection details dynamically?

Maybe there is a better approach, any comments/solutions are appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can create AWS S3 client dynamically by passing AccessKeyId, SecretAccessKey and Region. Here is the solution.

**AWS SDK v1.X**

```xml
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.315</version>
</dependency>
```

```java
@Service
public class AwsS3ClientBuilderService {

    public AmazonS3 createAwsS3Client(String accessKeyId, String secretAccessKey, String region){
        final BasicAWSCredentials basicAWSCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKeyId, secretAccessKey);
        return AmazonS3ClientBuilder
                .standard()
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(basicAWSCredentials))
                .withRegion(region)
                .build();
    }
}
```

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    private final AwsS3ClientBuilderService awsS3ClientBuilderService;

    @Autowired
    public DemoApplication(AwsS3ClientBuilderService awsS3ClientBuilderService) {
        this.awsS3ClientBuilderService = awsS3ClientBuilderService;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        final AmazonS3 amazonS3 = awsS3ClientBuilderService
                .createAwsS3Client("accessKeyId","secretAccessKey","eu-west-1");

        GetObjectRequest getObjectRequest = new GetObjectRequest("bucketName","keyName");
        final S3Object s3Object = amazonS3.getObject(getObjectRequest);
        final S3ObjectInputStream objectContent = s3Object.getObjectContent();
        //....
    }
}
```

**AWS SDK v2.X**

```xml
<dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>s3</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.285</version>
</dependency>
```

```java
@Service
public class AwsS3ClientBuilderService {

    public S3Client createAwsS3Client(String accessKeyId, String secretAccessKey, String region){
        AwsBasicCredentials awsBasicCredentials = AwsBasicCredentials.create(accessKeyId, secretAccessKey);
        return S3Client
                .builder()
                .region(Region.of(region))
                .credentialsProvider(StaticCredentialsProvider.create(awsBasicCredentials))
                .build();
    }
}
```

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    private final AwsS3ClientBuilderService awsS3ClientBuilderService;

    @Autowired
    public DemoApplication(AwsS3ClientBuilderService awsS3ClientBuilderService) {
        this.awsS3ClientBuilderService = awsS3ClientBuilderService;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        try (S3Client s3Client = awsS3ClientBuilderService
                .createAwsS3Client("accessKeyId", "secretAccessKey", "eu-west-1")) {
            GetObjectRequest getObjectRequest= GetObjectRequest
                    .builder()
                    .bucket("buketName")
                    .key("keyName")
                    .build();
            final ResponseInputStream<GetObjectResponse> responseInputStream = s3Client.getObject(getObjectRequest);
            final GetObjectResponse getObjectResponse = responseInputStream.response();
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for such a neat solution, my approach with prototype bean is really over-engineering :)

Comment: Good to know that you like the solution :)

Comment: The previous answer that uses AWS SDK for Java v1  is not using Best Practice Code. AWS SDK for Java v2 is best practice.   You can find many examples of using S3, Java V2 in the Code LIB here:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/java_2_code_examples.html

Comment: You can find a Spring Boot and S3 Java V2 API example in Code Lib -- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/cross_RekognitionPhotoAnalyzer_java_2_topic.html

Comment: @smac2020 - Thanks for pointing that out, I have updated my solution with both AWS SDK v1.x and SDK v2.x

Comment: WHen Possible - always try and use V2.

Comment: Yes, I will do that, added both versions just to help others who are still using the old version and don't want to migrate to the new version because of some constraints.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248909/discussion-between-rohit-agarwal-and-smac2020).